# How to add extra text in front of the bibliography number

Tags: bibliographies

I want `\cite{ref}` to give me the reference number, which should also be added in front of the citation in my bibliography, however I would like to add and extra text in front of my bibliography number in the bibliography. This means that in the reference list I would like to have this:

[34]reference

[database][35]reference

So I would like to add the word [database] in front of the bibliography number, but only for one specific entry.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{Dataset,
author       = {name1},
year         = {2018},
title        = {Dataset of something},
howpublished = {Mendeley Data},
}
@Article{Article,
author       = {name2},
year         = {2018},
title        = {Article of something},
howpublished = {Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
This is the text citation \cite{article} \cite{Dataset}, and it should 
remain like this
\section*{References}
Here I want to add [database] in front of the reference number of the 
database, but not for the article.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you give us some more details, in particular which documentclass and citation mechanism you are using, e.g. by posting a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: The answer crucially depends on the method you use to create your bibliography. Do you use the manual `thebibliography` way, BibTeX, `biblatex`? Which bibliography packages do you load `cite`, `natbib`, `jurbabib`, `biblatex`, ... Which style do you use? How do you want to identify the special entry that gets the "[database]" prefix? And why do you want to do this? These questions are best answered in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) (please read the links thoroughly).

Comment: @user162653 Are you sure that your documentclass is compatible with biblatex? It seems as if you are mixing biblatex and bibtex syntax...

Comment: The MWE definitely does not work as posted. `\printbibliography` and `\addbibresource` are `biblatex` commands, but the `elsarticle` class loads `natbib`. `biblatex` and `natbib` are incompatible. If you want to continue using `elsarticle`, you must remove `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography`. You must also call `\bibliography{<your bib file here>}` where you want your bibliography to appear in the document.

Comment: I think the code part now works. I want to add the [database] in front of the number, because I am writing an article for a journal and they aske for it during the revision process. That is also why I use the elsarticle class and bibstyle.